# R - How to input a list value into a function? Non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I am trying to input a value from my list of names into my function so that I can perform some calculations on it using values from a dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
## My list of names
name_list = list(c("A", "B"), c("C", "D"))

## Some random function to perform calculations
random_function = function(input){
    input/10
}

## The reason you see name_list[[1]][1] is because I wish to do this repeatedly for different list of names. 
data.frame("A"=c(1,1,2,2,3,4), "B"=c(1,3,5,7,9,11)) %>%
    mutate(A2 =  random_function(name_list[[1]][1]))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work and returns the error:
"non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Is there anyway around this?

What I want is essentially:

```
data.frame("A"=c(1,1,2,2,3,4), "B"=c(1,3,5,7,9,11)) %>%
    mutate(A2 =  random_function(A))
```

Comment: your input data is causing the problem. `(name_list[[1]][1]) = "A"`. when you try dividing `(name_list[[1]][1]) / 10` it throws an error `Error in (name_list[[1]][1])/10 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
       mutate_all(list(`2` = ~ random_function(.)))
```

---

Or if we need to do this based on 'name_list', convert to symbol and evaluage (`!!`)

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(A2 = random_function(!! rlang::sym(name_list[[1]][1])))
```

Or specify it in `mutate_at`

```
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(vars(name_list[[1]][1]), list(A2 = ~ random_function(.)))
```

Comment: Great, that does it! I never came across !!rlang::sym before. Still a lot to learn. May I ask if there is a general name for this kind of problem?

Comment: @mathnoob  You can check the vignettes of tidyverse along with rlang package for quosures and quasi evaluation